# checking list divisibility

Tags: haskell

How do I check if a list is divisible by 9

so far I tried

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main =  do   
        let line = [23,24, 30,35,36,40,42,44,54]
        putStrLn $ listofints line   

listofints :: [int] -> [int]  
listofints name = [x | x <- name, n `mod` x == 0]
```

I am getting an errors all over and I am very new to haskell

Please help me on how to write check if the list contains even integers and remove them from the list.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to  print? Any number divisble by nine?

Comment: I don't see you providing the value of `x` (which should be 2 for even numbers).

Comment: sorry about the header i want to check if number is dividable by 9 and remove it from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to print any number in `line` that is divisble by 9, you could use `filter`:

```haskell
main :: IO ()
main =  do   
        let line = [23,24, 30,35,36,40,42,44,54]
        print $ listofints line  

listofints :: [Int] -> [Int]
listofints = filter (\x -> x `mod` 9 == 0)
```

Comment: Awesome this is what I was looking for what does \x mean here I understand that x mod 9. I come from java background how does the main pass the line value to listofints function ( I am 99% sure that the $ functionname param does the trick but just confirming)

Comment: @rao `print $ listofints line` means (is parsed as) `print (listofints line)`. `listofints line` means a call to `listofints` with the argument value `line` and `()` (and `$`) are used for grouping.

Comment: @WillNess wjat does the \x mean how do haskell get the param from main method ? Sorry being from OOP background this is hard to understand

Comment: @rao `\x -> ...` is a lambda function, basically it's just an inline unnamed function. We need them because of the infix usage of `mod`. There were several bugs in your code above (can't use putStrLn with lists for example) and I can still remember how I made exactly the same mistakes as a beginner ;-)

Comment: @Uli Kohler does filter remove elements from the list, or just filters the even out,if filter does not remove from the list how do I remove the elements, I can post it as a new question if requred. For some reason I feel haskell has not much documented simple easy to follow examples and tutorials( may be a beginners point of view)

Comment: @rao try it yourself: `> filter even [1..4]` ==> `[2,4]`. -- and ***you are quite right about the documentation***. :)

Comment: @rao filter takes a function as the first argument. In our case, this function returns True for each value if it is div'able by 9. `filter` therefore removes *any* value that is not divisible by 9.

Comment: @WillNess and Uli Kohler Cant thank you enough, haskell seemed like cake walk with your help :D

Comment: @rao I somewhat agree to you and Will about the docs. I do Haskell for 4 weeks now, and it was **really** hard to get ahold of at the beginning. When you learn how to read the Hackage docs and after you've achieved to grasp the basic concepts, you'll see that they are not bad, but just not suitable for beginners.

Comment: @rao I recommend you *Learn you a haskell* and *Real world haskell* (for beginners, I prefer the first one). I just found out that on http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html there are excellent tutorials although I'm not sure if they have beginner tutorials.

Comment: @rao Another comment: I learned some of the basics by implementing some Project Euler tasks when I started with Haskell. This really helped me alot to get ahold of the many builtin funcs like map, filter, fold etc.

Comment: At the danger of getting accused of flag-spam here, Haskell *is* like cake, yummy!

Answer (score 3):

Going through this function by function

```
main :: IO ()
main =  do   
        let line = [23,24, 30,35,36,40,42,44,54]
        putStrLn $ listofints line
```

`putStrLn` works on strings, it's not like the generic "print" you get in python or similar. For that we have `print` :)

```
let line = ...
print $ listOfInts line
```

On to the next

```
listofints :: [Int] -> [Int] -- upper case  
listofints name = [x | x <- name, x `mod` n == 0]
```

You don't give a value for `n`, so that's an error. Try instead

```
 listofints name = [x | x <-name, x `mod` n == 0]
     where n = ???
```

where ??? is the value you want `n` to be, otherwise you can just inline it and get `` [..., x `mod` ??? == 0] ``.

Comment: Also, it should be `Int`, not `int`. `int` is a type variable, so `[int] -> [int]` is the same as `[a] -> [a]`.

Comment: @WillNess Indeed, I just copied it straight from the OP, whoops

Comment: Guys it will be much help if someone can point how do I use a remove function to remove elements from the list when the number is divisible by 9?

Comment: @rao what jozefg shows you here will *keep* all numbers divisible by ??? in a list. If you change `==` to `/=`, it will *remove* them instead (i.e. keep all numbers that are *not* divisible by ???). Just use 9 instead of ???.

Answer (score -1):

```
module Divison where
divisibility :: [Int] -> [String]
divisibility (x:xs) = map show([if x `mod` 9 == 0 && x `mod` 3 == 0 then "divideby3and9"
else if x `mod` 9 == 0 then "divideby9"
else if x `mod` 3 == 0 then "divideby3" else show(x) | x <- x:xs]
```

Comment: Hi! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.